# Postgres: run "pivot query" on foreign key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm running Postgres 9.6. We have two tables, the first is `user`:

```
id   | integer
name | varchar
```

And the second is `feature_flag`, which has a foreign key to `user`:

```
id   | integer
user_id | integer
```

I want to create a table users that shows (among other things) which feature flags the user has enabled - perhaps with an array column for feature flags (open to better suggestions, e.g. could be a column per feature flag with T/F).

So the results might look like this:

```
id,name,flags
1,foo,"[1,3]"
2,bar,"[1,2]"
```

Or like this:

```
id,name,flag_1,flag_2,flag_3
1,foo,T,F,T
2,bar,T,T,F
```

How do I do this? I know how to get a row for each flag per user:

```
   SELECT u.*, feature_flags 
   FROM "user" u
   OUTER JOIN feature_flag f on f.user_id=u.id
```

But then how do I pivot it up into the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate the flags:

```
SELECT u.*, array_agg(f.integer) as feature_flags
FROM "user" u
  LEFT JOIN feature_flag f on f.user_id=u.id
group by u.id;
```

The above requires that `"user".id` is the primary key of the table `"user"`

If you have an upper limit for the flags, you can use the following to create columns:

```
select id, name,
       1 = any(feature_flags) as flag_1, 
       2 = any(feature_flags) as flag_2, 
       3 = any(feature_flags) as flag_3, 
       .... 
from (
  SELECT u.*, array_agg(f.integer) as feature_flags
  FROM "user" u
    LEFT JOIN feature_flag f on f.user_id=u.id
  group by u.id
) t
```